# How to convert smoke sim to mesh?

Tags: mesh, smoke-simulation

How can I convert a smoke sim to mesh?

I tried:

1. new default cube scene
2. Objects --> Quick Effects --> Quick Smoke
3. Modifier Properties --> Volume to Mesh

After the above steps, the Quick Smoke disappears.

I want to make something [similar to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QMuXQH_5ZA):
[image]

but animated with smoke simulation and without having to manually export and import volumes

Comment: Why don't you just follow the tutorial? It's for 2.91, but Mantaflow didn't change that much since then. [Blender Tutorial - Volume to Mesh Modifier w/ Mantaflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QMuXQH_5ZA) Simply entered "blender smoke to mesh" in the Youtube search and the image you're showing here is the thumbnail of the video.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I think it's because of the last part *"but animated ... and without having to manually export and import volumes"*

Comment: @Blunder Yeah, but the sentence "After the above steps, the Quick Smoke disappears" sounded to me as if it doesn't even work to get the volume... because, simply adding a _Volume to Mesh_ modifier (as it sounds in the question) is not how it works. And since on this site it is preferred to only have one question per thread I thought, one after another.